# 'Post' object is not iterable:TypeError

Tags: python, django, templates, model

This is my view . I have used function based view to show to detail of post.

```
def post_detail(request,slug,pk):
    detail = get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug,pk=pk)
    context={
        'detail':detail
    }
    return render(request,'post/post_detail.html',context)
```

This is my urls . of post_detail , and its name is also post_detail

```
path('<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

This is my models. It is a post model I have got get_absolute_url () to render to detail view

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    story= models.TextField()
    image= models.ImageField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk,'slug':self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is the post/post_detail.html for my post_detail view

```
 {% extends "post/base.html" %}
 {% block content %}
 {% for posts in detail %}
 {{posts.image.url}}
 {{posts.title}}
 Written by: {{posts.author}}

{% endfor %}

 {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your detail template, you don't need a `for` loop; As you are just passing **one** post to the template:

```
{% block content %}

{{detail.image.url}}
{{detail.title}}

Written by: {{detail.author}}
{% endblock content %}
```